# Dynamic values are not being retained in controls in HTML while clicking back button in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am having two select list in my html page. one list is dependent on another.
based on the selection of one list second list is getting populated. when i click submit button my page redirect to different page. on click of back the dependent select list is being reset.
i know chrome doesn't support bfcache like firefox. 
is there any way to achieve the same?
 i wrote below method which is being called on onchange event of dependent select list:

```
function storePickListIndexAndValueInSession( source_field, dest_field, form1 )
  {
  var dependentField = form1[dest_field];
  var parentField = form1[source_field];
  if(dependentField.value != null  && dependentField.value != '' && dependentField.value != 'undefined' )
  {
    sessionStorage.setItem('Dependent'+dest_field+'LastSelectedValue',dependentField.selectedIndex );
    sessionStorage.setItem('Independent'+source_field+'LastSelectedValue',parentField.value );
  }

  else if (parentField.value != null  && parentField.value != '' && parentField.value != 'undefined' )
  {
    var arr = dependentField.options;
    if(parentField.value === sessionStorage.getItem('Independent'+source_field+'LastSelectedValue') )
    {   
        var arrElem = arr[sessionStorage.getItem('Dependent'+dest_field+'LastSelectedValue')];
        if( arrElem != null && arrElem != '' && arrElem != 'undefined')
        dependentField.selectedIndex = arr[sessionStorage.getItem('Dependent'+dest_field+'LastSelectedValue')].index;
        else
        dependentField.selectedIndex = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        sessionStorage.setItem('Independent'+source_field+'LastSelectedValue',parentField.value );
        dependentField.selectedIndex = 0;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    sessionStorage.setItem('Dependent'+dest_field+'LastSelectedValue',0 );
  }
  }
```

but this method is not working in case if we do not have a null value/empty value in select lists.
Thanks in advance.